# How do I add a custom button to the Android Nav Bar in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I am aware that I can add a button by modifying some version of the ***navigation_bar.xml*** file located in ***/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res***. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053803/5992240) is an example of the file. After I add it, I know I can wire it up using the `systemui:keyCode` attribute.

With the above approach, I can only wire up functionality using the preset keycodes however. My question is, how do I add any kind of custom functionality? For example, if I wanted to add a button to open some app, where would I add the `OnClickListener` logic to launch said app?